# Azure Synapse (Azure Data Factory) REST source pagination with dynamic limit

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, etl, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse I'm performing a data copy action. It has a REST API as a source and needs to store this data in a on-premise SQL table. The whole setup is configured and the table is filled with 100 records. This is a limit from the API. It returns 100 records by default. The total amount of data that I need to collect from this endpoint is somewhere around the 150000 records and grows by day.

I saw that pagination might help me here. That everything when 100 records are collected I can start collecting the next 100 records up and until I've reached the total data set. I don't want to set the total limit in the configuration, I would like to see that it is being collected dynamically until it reaches the maximum by itself.

How can I set this up?

Thanks in advance!

I've set pagination with header value 'skip' and this refers to the relative URL which I defined like:
?take=100&skip={skip}. I've tried to work with the value parameters but I've no clue how to set that up.

Comment: Please share what you have tried and error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to set the total limit in the configuration, I would like to see that it is being collected dynamically until it reaches the maximum by itself.

**To achieve this scenario, we need to Follow 2 steps:**

1. Set **"AbsoluteUrl.offset": "RANGE:0::20"**, In the range of **Pagination rules** and leave the end of range empty. Here it will start from 0 and end is not defined with offset of 20.
2. **Set End Condition** rules according to different last responses. **otherwise, pipeline run will not stop as we have not provided any end to range of pagination**
   Here I used the pagination ends when the value of the header key in response equals to user-defined const value as my data contain id if it is equal to 2000 it will stop the pipeline run

[image]

- My sample data: It contains around 100 objects
  [image]
- My dataset setting:
  [image]
- Preview after pagination rule: I have set offset as 20 and limit/take as 1 because of this it is showing only 5 objects (just to check if it is going till last data or not).
  [image]
- pipeline completed successfully
  [image]

refer [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#example-4variables-are-in-absoluteurlqueryparametersheaders-the-end-variable-is-not-pre-defined-and-the-end-condition-is-based-on-the-response) for more understanding on pagination rule